# JEuclid - set a size of an image converted from MathML

Tags: java, image, mathml

I'm looking for a way to set an output image dimension after a MathML to Image convertion. I wrote a simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Converter converter = Converter.getInstance();
    converter.convert(new File("C:\\test.html"),
        new File("C:\\out.jpg"), "image/jpeg");
}
```

test.html looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE math PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD MathML 2.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/dtd/mathml2.dtd">
<math mode="display">
  <mrow>
    <munderover>
      <mo>&#x222B;</mo>
      <mn>1</mn>
      <mi>x</mi>
    </munderover>
    <mfrac>
      <mi>dt</mi>
      <mi>t</mi>
    </mfrac>
  </mrow>
 </math>
```

And as a result I get an Image with dimesion 21x37px. As far I've tried something with (but it does not work):

```
MutableLayoutContext params = new LayoutContextImpl(
            LayoutContextImpl.getDefaultLayoutContext());
    params.setParameter(Parameter.?, ?);
```

Do you know a way I could manipulate this dimesion ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, the param that helps here is:

```
params.setParameter(Parameter.MATHSIZE, 50f);
```

Comment: I found that the "<mstyle>" tags could be a problem here, so to make it work I had to get rid of them first